# Why my file is not uploading to S3 using Node.js

Tags: file-upload, node.js, amazon-s3

I am using this 
https://github.com/nuxusr/Node.js---Amazon-S3
for uploading files to s3 :

in `test-s3-upload.js` i had commented mostly tests because they was giving some error , as my goal is to upload the file to s3 so i keep only `testUploadFileToBucket()` test and while running `node test.js` gives ok.

but when i check in s3 fox the uploaded file is not being shown.
why file is not uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use knox instead. https://github.com/learnboost/knox

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this project and especially the bin/amazon-s3-upload.js file so you can see how we're doing it using AwsSum:

- https://github.com/appsattic/node-awssum-scripts/
- https://github.com/appsattic/node-awssum/

It takes a bucket name and a filename and will stream the file up to S3 for you:

$ ./amazon-s3-upload.js -b your-bucket -f the-file.txt

Hope that helps. :)